# Watson Virtual Angent: Find Nearest Store module and Invoke client Workspace

Tags: watson-conversation, watson, watson-virtual-agent

I'm trying to use my Workspace intents in order to recive as an answer the map visualization of the nearest store.

The problem is that: if use Invoke client Workspace how can I insert the data to visualize the map in the dialog flow as an answer to a user request about the nearest store so it is when I use IBM Content?

Thanks for any helps,

Filippo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add to your custom dialog the following:
(extracted from https://github.com/watson-virtual-agents/virtual-agent-dialog/blob/master/dialog-contract.md?cm_mc_uid=77031076060014712594367&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1477519039)

```
{
    "output": {
        "text": "Select your store",
        "layout": {
            "name": "show-locations"
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "request": {
            "args": {
                "location": "$user_location",
                "location-type": "$location_type"
            },
            "name": "getStoreList"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let me see if I understood. Do you want send a map location to the users based on their intent to the Conversation messaging.
First- Conversation is only the API where you can use the request/response Machine Learning embedded in you app.
Second- Based on the user`s message you need to create a logic in your app to request a map or check a db list to show the option.
On the basic application using the Conversation API, you should focus on your Backend where you will create the services for the business and ux layers. Until this moment, this location will not appear directly (otherwise you need to create entities with all stores and all locations to answer it without request a DB to provide you a list.
Good Luck

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  I would suggest you make this a comment to the original question.